# SFML crashes at first call using Code::Blocks

Tags: c++, codeblocks, sfml

I am using SFML 1.6 with Code::Blocks 12.11 on a windows 8.1 computer. I have been having problems so I made a very simple test program, which looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SFML/System.hpp>
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main(){
    std::cout<<"Start"<<std::endl;
    sf::Sprite test;
    std::cout<<"End"<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When I try to run this it prints Start, then crashes. I have checked my linker settings and I think they are right because it compiles just fine with no errors or warnings. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: More important: What compiler/linker are you using? What's the crash message you're  getting? If you're using Visual C++, you're most likely using the wrong library files.

Comment: Code::Blocks 12.11 using Mingw GCC GNU compiler 4.8 (or somewhere around there, I will have to check later) and the window just freezes and windows brings up a window that says the program is not responding

Comment: You should definitely update to SFML 2.x, SFML 1.6 is already over 1000 commits behind, has serious bugs that will never get fixed and lacks a good build system. With every new version of compiler, you need to recompile SFML, thus if you didn't do so it won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually missed the fact that you're running SFML 1.6. I've tried your code with the latest build from [GitHub](https://github.com/LaurentGomila/SFML/) and it runs just fine. Either this is some bug in 1.6 or you're doing something wrong somewhere else (you shouldn't see any program window unless you're creating one yourself).

Try downloading the latest version (2.1) from the [downloads page](http://sfml-dev.org/download/sfml/2.1/) and see whether it crashes as well. Right now I guess it crashes due to the incompatibility mentioned [in this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14905842/sfmlc-crash-upon-creation-of-window-sfml1-6-cb12-11?rq=1). Try running `g++ -v` from the command line to determine the exact version of GCC you're running.